# How to use the "return" value of an inner loop in an outer loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want to use the value of the inner `each` loop in the outer loop to pass it as an argument.

```
namespace :office do
  desc "send reminder emails"
  task send_reminder: :environment do
    Office.all.each do |office|
      office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
        issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last # I will get billing_ids here which I want to pass as arguments in the outer loop.
      end
      ReminderWorker.perform_async(billing_ids)
    end
  end
end
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Office.all.each do |office|
      billing_ids=[] #initialize array
      office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
        billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id #add id to array
      end
      ReminderWorker.perform_async(billing_ids)
    end
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now. But I just want to access the ID element from the array. But when I try to extract it by doing something like this puts "#{billings_ids["id"]}" I am getting an error **TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer**

Comment: It is not a hash. It is just an array of id (e.g. [1,2,3,4]). You can just simply get the value by index: billings_ids[0], billings_ids[1]. Or through loop: billing_ids.each do |id|

Comment: When answering, please explain why your answer solves the problem and why it is the appropriate solution. The goal isn't to simply toss out code, it's to educate so if the problem occurs again the OP knows how to handle it.